# Quarto cutting off diagrams with columns

Tags: r, graphviz, quarto

I've been working to try and make a slide for a presentation with a 4x4 set of figures showing four different Directed Acyclic Graphs. However, it seems that Quarto won't resize the diagrams for the columns. I tried simplifying this down and noticed that not only would it not resize them, but, it would also cut off graphs if a column width was too narrow.  Here is a reprex showing this odd behavior. What can I do here to have quarto diagrams respect the column resizing?

First, this looks fine.

````
---
title: "test"
format: revealjs
---

# DAG Before You Model

```{dot}
digraph {

layout = neato

m [
    shape = none
    pos = "-1,1!"
]

d [
    shape = none
    pos = "0,0!"
]


a [
    shape = none
    pos = "1,1!"
]


m -> d
a -> d
}
````

[image: works]

But, with this modification, things get weird and cut-off.

````
---
title: "test"
format: revealjs
---

# DAG Before You Model

::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}

```{dot}
digraph {

layout = neato

m [
    shape = none
    pos = "-1,1!"
]

d [
    shape = none
    pos = "0,0!"
]


a [
    shape = none
    pos = "1,1!"
]


m -> d
a -> d
}
```

:::


::: {.column width="50%"}
:::

:::
````

[image: The cutoff diagram]

If you mess with the column widths, you can start getting the cutoff part back, but, the diagram never resizes.

Running quarto 1.4.549 R 4.3.2

Comment: This looks like a bug. Maybe you can submit an issue?